# Every plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is from Pressley's Differential Geometry. Let $a$ be a point on the plane and let $p$ and $q$ be two unit vectors parallel to the plane and orthogonal to each other. If $\mathbf{r}$ is any point on the plane then $\mathbf{r-a}$ is parallel to the plane, and so $$\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{a}=u\mathbf{p}+v\mathbf{q}$$ for scalars $u,v$. So now we have the surface patch $\sigma(u,v) = \mathbf{a} + u\mathbf{p}+v\mathbf{q}$. Now the book states that its inverse is $\sigma^{-1}(\mathbf r) = ((\mathbf r-\mathbf a)\cdot\mathbf p,(\mathbf r- \mathbf a)\mathbf q)$.

Now my problem is that I have no idea how the inverse was found. Could someone explain it to me.

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @mrsamy Pressley's Differential Geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that
$$ \newcommand{\v}\mathbf \v r-\v a = u \v p + v \v q$$
and we want to solve for $u$ and $v$. Of course we can rearrange and get
$$ \newcommand{\v}\mathbf  u \v p =\v r-\v a - v \v q \tag{1}$$
How can we  get rid of the $\v p$? Well recall the definition of $\v p, \v q$ being orthogonal and unit length,
$$ \v p \cdot \v p = 1 = \v q \cdot \v q, \\ \v p \cdot \v q = 0.$$
So if we take the dot product of $(1)$ with $\v p$, we are left with
$$ u = \v r\cdot\v p-\v a \cdot\v p  - v \v q \cdot\v p = (\v r - \v a) \cdot \v p$$
which is precisely the first component of the inverse given to you. Similarly with the second.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sigma(u,v)=\mathbf{r}$ and $\sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{r})=(u,v)$. On the other hand, the formula $\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{a}=u\mathbf{p}+v\mathbf{q}$ implies that
$$
u=(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{a})\cdot \mathbf{p},\quad v=(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{a})\cdot \mathbf{q}
$$

by orthogonality of the vectors $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ (and that they are of length $1$).